# direct login is possible without login screen in azure ad b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 websites one is an old version and 2nd is the new version. I connect both applications with the single sign on. Once I come from the old version website to the new version at that time I want to direct login inside azure ad b2c with out login screen is it possible to use a single sign-on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats default behaviour. There is nothing to configure.

Comment: I mean can I skip the login page and direct login is possible without that?

Comment: Yes, that is default.

Comment: if I want to skip the azure ad b2c login page then it possible?

Comment: It is the default behaviour to skip the login pages once the user already has an active session at AAD B2C, this provides SSO behaviour when logging into app2 after logging into app1.

Comment: How do I login inside Azure Ad b2c using SSO from the background?

Comment: You can call MSAL ssoSilent() method in your app when the user is not authenticated. That will do a hidden iframe authentication against B2C using SSO cookies. Or, in your app call acquireTokenRedirect() MSAL method to perform SSO via full page redirect through B2C - this is the default option.

Comment: acquireTokenRedirect() from where I get this sample code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integrate-with-app-code-samples

Comment: Can you guide me if it is possible or not?
how we can log in users to AAD B2C after SSO without a login screen?

Comment: Any Updates on the previous question?

Comment: If you spin up two sample apps, and test it, you’ll see that it just works. And the JavaScript sample uses acquireTokenRedirect()

Comment: is it possible to connect on skype for the current task running task?

Comment: Please revert on a priority base.